# How to check if one composable is on the same y position to another? (Arrow indicates to element from the scrollable column)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to change the item image (above the arrow) depending on the pokemon on the right. User can vertically scroll items. I need to get the item which the arrow indicates on and handle indicated item change caused by scroll.
Example:

1. arrow indicates on "Vaporeon"
2. User scrolls to "Jolteon" (this yellow item)
3. While the user is scrolling, the image above the arrow should change to an image related to "Jolteon" at the moment of starting indicating on him
4. Image stays as is until the arrow is indicating on the other item than "Jolteon"
5. And when another element is indicated then we repeat this flow but with another element

Images:
[image: Initial state]

[image: Scrolling state]

This is the view that can be scrolled horizontal (next evolution) and vertical (evolution variants):

```
@Composable
private fun EvolutionChainContent(
    parentPokemonDetails: PokemonDetails,
    pokemonEvolutionSteps: List<EvolutionStep>,
    navigateToPokemonDetails: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val commonScrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {
        pokemonEvolutionSteps.forEach { evolutionStep ->
            val columnScrollState =
                if (evolutionStep.pokemonDetailList.hasOneItem()) rememberScrollState()
                else commonScrollState
            if (pokemonEvolutionSteps.isNotFirstElement(evolutionStep)) {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 115.dp)
                ) {
                    // TODO change to currently indicated by arrow
                    EvolutionRuleView(evolutionStep.pokemonEvolutionDetails.first())
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(5.dp))
                    ArrowToNextEvolution(parentPokemonDetails.types.first().getTypeColor())
                }
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(250.dp)
                    .drawVerticalScrollbar(columnScrollState)
                    .verticalScroll(columnScrollState)
            ) {
                evolutionStep.pokemonDetailList.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
                    PokemonItem(
                        pokemonDetails = it,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(155.dp)
                            .height(230.dp),
                        onClick = if (parentPokemonDetails.name != it.name) {
                            { navigateToPokemonDetails(it.name) }
                        } else null
                    )
                    if (evolutionStep.pokemonDetailList.isLastElement(it))
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a couple other components, so i leave here link to github repository and to folder with ui components of this view: [Github repo - evolution chain](https://github.com/arix2000/Pokedex/tree/develop/app/src/main/java/com/arix/pokedex/features/pokemon_details/presentation/ui/components/evolution_chain) as well as with whole project

I have tried handle this with `onGlobalPosition()` but i couldn't control y position well.
I also tried to use LazyColumn istead of Column but it causes error because I have also vertical scrolling on the root.
Feel free to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `Column` with `LazyColumn`. `LazyListState` has many parameters, such as:

```kotlin
val firstVisibleItemIndex: Int
val firstVisibleItemScrollOffset: Int
val layoutInfo: LazyListLayoutInfo
```

It should be easy to use these to achieve the effect you want.

---

A month ago I tried to implement LazyColumn in scrollable Column using nestedScroll. it was a nightmare. But considering that your Item height is fixed, you can just calculate the current index.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ) {
        val size = 9
        val state = rememberScrollState()
        var index by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            snapshotFlow { state.value }
                .collect { index = (it.toFloat() * (size - 1) / state.maxValue).roundToInt() }
        }

        Text(text = "It is ${index + 1}")
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(250.dp)
                .verticalScroll(state),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
        ) {
            repeat(size) {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier.size(230.dp),
                    border = BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Red),
                ) {
                    Box {
                        Text(
                            text = (it + 1).toString(),
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                            style = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(fontSize = 40.sp),
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is LazyColumn causes error. Do you know how to place LazyColumn with vertical scroll in the another Column with vertical scroll?

Comment: Well, I solved this by onGloballyPositioned callback but your solution looks much cleaner and more precise. I tested that, and that works, so thank you!